# IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I have two different Active Directories, for first Azure Active Directory (where I am owner and can make changes), I am able to login and get token, but for second Active Directory provided by customer with same C# code I am getting this exception:

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
>   (IsReadOnly = False, Count = 1,
>   Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause)

My code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365) });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                // TokenValidationParameters allows you to control the users who are allowed to sign in
                // to your application. In this demo we only allow users associated with the specified tenant. 
                // If ValidateIssuer is set to false, anybody with a personal or work Microsoft account can 
                // sign in.
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = tenant
                },

                // OpenIdConnect event handlers/callbacks.
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }

            });
}
```

Thanks in advance if you help me finding the problem and suggesting solution.

Comment: What are the configurations you have changed?

Comment: I have changed "ClientId", "ClientSecret" and "Tenant"

Comment: What is the value of authority?

Comment: <add key="ida:Tenant" value="GUID" />

string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";

 private string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

Comment: All seems fine, which sample did you refer to? I will try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with two different Azure AD tenants by using the same code. Both of them works as expected.

Here are the steps.

1. Register an application->add a web platform with redirect uri->check Access token and ID tokens

[image]

2.Get clientId and tenantId from the application

[image]

3.Paste the values in web.config file

[image]

So you need to ask your customer to check the application they registered.

Comment: Thanks Tony Ju, i will get back on it after discussing current situation with customer.

Comment: I took new app from customer and used its configuration keys in website then deployed on public URL, there it authenticated and worked. But it still did not work on localhost! anyways thanks for you help!